# How to configure kollmorgen drive with CANopen?

Tags: can-bus, canopen

I want to configure a Kollmorgen drive to rotate a motor with constant velocity via CANopen. I am using SDO mode for it.
My drive device id is 0614. So far I have configured it as:

```
Id=0614, Data= 2F 04 22 00 50 00 00 00 'Set run current to 80%
Id=0614, Data= 23 84 60 00 40 42 0F 00 'Set deceleration to 1M steps/sec^2
Id=0614, Data= 23 83 60 00 40 42 0F 00 'Set acceleration to 1M steps/sec^2
```

Enable motor power

```
Id=0614, Data= 2B 40 60 00 06 00 00 00 'Ready to Switch on
Id=0614, Data= 2B 40 60 00 07 00 00 00 'Switched on
Id=0614, Data= 2B 40 60 00 0F 00 00 00 'Operation Enable
```

Set to Profile Velocity Mode

```
Id=0614, Data= 2F 60 60 00 03 00 00 00 'Set to Profile Velocity Mode
```

Target Velocity -

```
Id=0614, Data= 23 FF 60 00 50 C3 00 00 'Target Velocity 50K
```

The problem I am facing is that whenever I am trying to enable the drive it gets disabled automatically. When I try to read StatusWord is gives 0270. Which means the device is disabled. It doesn't give any warning or fault.

Comment: Just as additional input for anyone working on a similar application: Check if your drive additionally requires an electrical ["hardware enable" signal](http://curvegen.kollmorgen.com/webhelp/workbench/english/Content/UsersManual/Enabling%20and%20Disabling%20the%20Drive.htm) set to high.

Answer (score 0):

the device Id in canopen protocol could not be bigger than 127. the COB ID of SDO download is  0x600+nodeID and the COB ID of SDO upload is 0x580+nodeID
I think the Id of your device is 0x14.also  sdo DOWNLOAD message just include 4 bytes of data and the second third and fourth data are including the address OD 'S index and sub index that you want write to it and the first byte is specifier that is shown below 
[image: sdo download message format]

[image]